# Using Pandas match='string' parameter in pd.read_html does not recognize the string in a table, even though there is a table containing 'string'

Tags: python, pandas

This question has two parts:

**Part One**
I'm trying to scrape some data from the SEC's website using pandas pd.read_html function.  I only want one specific table, which has the text "Principal Position" in the table.  I wrote a script (see below) to pull this data, but the problem is that it only works some of the time.  Sometimes it seems to completely ignore tables that contain this text.

For instance, in the script below, I attempt to pull the table containing the words "Principal Position" for each of three companies - Microsoft, Amazon, and Tesla.  Although all three companies have a table containing the words "Principal Position", only two of the tables (MSFT and TSLA) are scraped.  The third (AMZN) is skipped in the try-except block because the text is not found.  I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong that is causing the AMZN table to be skipped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Part Two**
I'm also trying to figure out how to cause the table to have headers that start with whatever row contains the words "Principal Position."  Sometimes this phrase is in the second row, sometimes the third, etc.  I can't figure out how to set the headers parameter in pd.read_html to be dynamic so that it changes based on whichever row contains the words "Principal Position."

Ideally I would also like to get rid of the extra columns that are inserted into the table (i.e., the columns that are all 'NaN' values).

I know I'm asking a ton but thought I'd throw it out there to see if anyone knows how to do this (I'm stumped).  Again, greatly appreciate any help!

**My code (which skips AMZN table but does scrape the MSFT and TSLA tables)**

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

CIK_list = {'MSFT': 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312519268531/d791036ddef14a.htm',
            'AMZN': 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1018724/000119312520108422/d897711ddef14a.htm',
            'TSLA': 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459020027321/tsla-def14a_20200707.htm',}

for ticker, link in CIK_list.items():
    try:
        df_list = pd.read_html(link, match=('Principal Position'))
        df_list = pd.DataFrame(df_list[0])
        df_list.to_csv(f'Z:/Python/{ticker}.csv')
    except:
        pass
```

EDITED POST:  To add a bit of detail, the error I am receiving is as follows:

```
ValueError: No tables found matching pattern 'Principal Position'
```

However, if you look at the link to the AMZN filing, you can text search for "Principal Position" and it comes up.  Could it be that somehow Pandas is not waiting for the page to fully load before executing read_html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df_list = pd.read_html(link, match=('Principal\s+Position'))
```

Because looking at the html code, there appears to be more than just a single [whitespace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) between Principal and Position for the AMZN webpage.  Using `\s+` regex, which means one or more space will capture this table also.

[image]